# Tab index not work on image, panel and Group tags in flash

Tags: flash, actionscript, flex4, tabindex

I am writing code to order the tab on multiple tags like "img","Panel","LinkButton",...
and pie charts. when I run my flash program, the tab indexing does not work at all. it just works on pie chart and "link button" tags, not on "img","Panel","Group" tags. I also have tried to "enable tab" on those fields , but no help.on the other hand when I disable tab on the pie chart, and link button, still the tab is enabled.

I have searched a lot and could not find a solution yet. appreciate a lot if someone could help me
I am working on Flash 10.0.0.0 , sdk 4.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to implement the IFocusMangerComponent in order to get the focus for image. although the "tab index" is available in the  class, if you want to get the tab to work on image, you have to simply implement IFocusMangerComponent as following in .as file. (no need to implement the functions in the new class)

import mx.controls.Image;
import mx.managers.IFocusManagerComponent;

```
  public class FocusableImage extends Image implements IFocusManagerComponent
  {
            public function FocusableImage()
            {
                      super();
            }
  }
```

then in the code instead of using    var image = new Image() , you have to use

```
var image = new FocusableImage() 
   image.tabEnabled = true;
   image.tabFocusEnabled = true;
   image.tabIndex = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are looking for **tabEnabled** and **tabIndex**, both properties of flash.display.InteractiveObject
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/InteractiveObject.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6

You might also want to take a look at Stage.focus
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Stage.html#focus

If you can give more details about your issue I'll try to help you with a more direct answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I already know about tabIndex and TabEnabled, but I figured from Adobe forum employee(http://forums.adobe.com/thread/909209)  that I cannot use them directly in order to tab on image,... I have to implement IFocusMangerComponent class in order to be able to order my tabs in images. the point is I could not get that to work and don;t know how to do that. I could not find a simple example on how to do tab on images using IFocusMangerComponent